# Use of static class variable other than constants

Tags: java, static

My professor wants a "non-trivial" answer to the question of "What are the uses of a static class variable, besides constants?"

Aside from constants, the only one I can think of is keeping a count of the objects that have been instantiated from the class.

Comment: Read up on singletons.

Comment: a google search of "uses of static variables" would be faster than making this question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Practice: Java static non final variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731236/best-practice-java-static-non-final-variables)

Answer (score 0):

A certainly *non-trivial* answer to this question can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

In short, they're used to keep global state for the class and make our lives as developers worse for fighting hard to reason about tests.

Comment: Now that we have dependency injection, I consider singletons to be evil, as well.

Comment: In the era of `microservices` hype and increasing need (and demand) for horizontal scalability, singletons are coming to my mind as `code smell`, since they (usually) affect ability to scale